# How to get value within an Excel workbook in Sharpoint into Active workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I have an excel workbook that needs to get data from an excel workbook hosted in a Sharepoint document library. Creating a list from the source file is not an option :/

I am able to open the source excel file but I don't want the user to see it opening.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest that you copy the file locally:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y(v=vs.90).aspx and then access the file (without opening it) using ADO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415326/search-workbook-and-extract-data-without-opening-it-excel-vba Afterwards you can delete the local copy of that file.

Comment: The solution was surprisingly simple. Turning off screen update was enough, assumed it would not apply for newly opened workbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly simple.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Was also thinking it would be a performance issue creating a whole workbook process but works without a hitch.